# SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (Curl::Err::SSLPeerCertificateError)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, curb

I got the error on ubuntu but works on mac

But if I run the curl command on ubuntu , it works. is curb a buggy gem?

```
2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.6/lib/curl/easy.rb:72:in `perform': SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (Curl::Err::SSLPeerCertificateError)
```

### RUBY

```
resp = Curl::Easy.http_post(server_url, content_to_send) do |curl|
  curl.ssl_verify_peer = false
  curl.headers = header.clone
end
```

### Detail

```
/home/poc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.6/lib/curl/easy.rb:72:in `perform': SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (Curl::Err::SSLPeerCertificateError)
    from /home/poc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.6/lib/curl/easy.rb:398:in `http_post'
    from /home/poc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.6/lib/curl/easy.rb:398:in `http_post'
    from curb.rb:12:in `curl_query'
    from curb.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is `server_url` starting with `https://`?

Comment: My guess is you are to handle the `SSL` transfer more carefully. I’m not a `curl` guru, but would you ming to try to play with different `ssl_*` options? http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/1.9.3/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-Peer+Verification

Comment: it works on my mac but not ubuntu , i think there are environment issue but i have no ideaT_T

Comment: Having this same issue with this error happening on CentOS 5 but not on my Mac - any success fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error, turns out for linux machines you need `ssl_verify_host=0`

To be safe I use both:

```
resp = Curl::Easy.http_post(server_url, content_to_send) do |curl|
  curl.ssl_verify_peer = false
  curl.ssl_verify_host = 0
  curl.headers = header.clone
end
```

Also a heads up—you might be developing on mac, but deploying to a server running linux, so better to use both even on a mac.